# How to access environment variable from rails on your javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set up a key system in the application I'm building. I have a code that has this logic:

```
$('.key-test-button').on('click', function(){
    if ($('.key-test-input').val() === "MYKEYHERE"){
        $('#hidden-div-instructor').show();
    } 
});
```

And My Idea was to replace "MYKEYHERE" for a hidden value on my code that I would store as a environment variable. I know how to do that for APIs for example, inside rails, but Im not familiar how I could access this variable inside my javascript/jquery script. I would love if someone could give me a insight. Thanks you.

Comment: You will need to pass it into the page/js.  You could use a .js.erb in the js file for the specific view you're dealing with.

Comment: @Thais good way to pass variables through html data attribute and then used in ur javascript

Answer (score 2):

As @davidhoelzer mentioned, you can't do this with pure js (as far as I know)...  you could, however, change the .js file to .js.erb and use ruby to access/manipulate your environment variable that way.

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone.