# How do I embed an environment variable into a .coffee file in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I saw this question, but it didn't work: [How to access environment variable from rails on your javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374229/how-to-access-environment-variable-from-rails-on-your-javascript)

I have this code

`subscriptions.coffee.erb`

```
$ ->
  # Create a Stripe client
  stripe = Stripe( "<% ENV['STRIPE_PUBLIC'] %>" )
```

And I have this environment set

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\>echo %STRIPE_PUBLIC%
pk_test_7aMtxxxxxxxxxxxxx4p3M

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\>rails server --bind 0.0.0.0
=> Booting Puma
```

Yet it is generating this JS:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/subscriptions.self-dfceb50c7f2eec8201fd3f59a7660a6763333b1e27f564e812f93c8ce9019188.js?body=1

(function() {
  $(function() {
    var card, elements, form, stripe, stripeTokenHandler, style;
    stripe = Stripe("");
```

Comment: For others landing here, I was able to use `<%= ENV[ "MY_VAR" ] %>` inside of a `.js.coffee` file by just adding `.erb` to the filename, like `.js.coffee.erb`. Just remember that this is processed in "ERB" when the assets are precompiled which usually happens right after a deploy on the server so it's very limited to what you can access. I also didn't test this in production, just in development so make sure to test and test again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one had an answer for me and I couldn't wait all day so I did it a different way.

`_form.haml`

```
=javascript_include_tag 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/'
:javascript
  window.stripe_public = "#{ENV['STRIPE_PUBLIC']}";
```

`subscriptions.coffee`

```
$ ->
  # Create a Stripe client
  stripe = Stripe( window.stripe_public )
```

yields

`view-source:http://localhost:3000/users/1/subscriptions/new`

```
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <script>
    window.stripe_public = "pk_test_7xxxxxxxxxxxx4p3M";
  </script>
```

`http://localhost:3000/assets/subscriptions.self-dfceb50c7f2eec8201fd3f59a7660a6763333b1e27f564e812f93c8ce9019188.js?body=1`

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    var card, elements, form, stripe, stripeTokenHandler, style;
    stripe = Stripe(window.stripe_public);
```

Comment: According to timestamps, you waited just 23 minutes between posting your question and this answer...

Answer (score 3):

In your template, you're missing a `=` to actually render the output of the ERB expression. The following should work:

```
stripe = Stripe("<%= ENV['STRIPE_PUBLIC'] %>")
```

See [the docs](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_template_erb.html#expression-printing-tags) for more.

Comment: Ooh... I generally only use HAML. Oops.

Comment: Oh, unfortunately this doesn't work on Heroku with pre-compiled assets. Apparently when it pre-compiles the Javascript, it doesn't contain the environment variables set via `heroku config`.